# Bound for $K_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\dfrac{1}{i^{(\alpha+1)}}.\dfrac{1}{(n-i)^{(\alpha+1)}}, \alpha>1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, inequality, upper-lower-bounds

I would like to bound the sum $$K_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\dfrac{1}{i^{(\alpha+1)}}.\dfrac{1}{(n-i)^{(\alpha+1)}}.$$
My attempt yield:
$$K_n \leq \dfrac{1}{(n-1)^{\alpha}}+\dfrac{1}{(n-1)^{\alpha}}
 \leq \dfrac{1}{(n-1)^{\alpha}}.$$

However, running some numerical simulation on $\alpha = 1, 1.5, 1.7, 2:
n^{\alpha + 1}K$, seems bounded,
$n^{\alpha + 1-0.01}K$ is decreasing in n for n up to $10^7$, though decreases very slowly $n^{\alpha + 1 - 1/2}K$, decreases rapidly for n up to $10^7$

The numerics would suggest that $n^{-\alpha}$ is not optimal as a bound for $K$ and perhaps $n^{-(\alpha + 1)}$ is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $$K_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\dfrac{1}{i^{(\alpha+1)}}.\dfrac{1}{(n-i)^{(\alpha+1)}}$$
We have
$$K_n < \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \left( \dfrac{1}{i^{(\alpha+1)}}+\dfrac{1}{(n-i)^{(\alpha+1)}}\right)\frac{1}{ (n/2)^{\alpha+1}}  < \frac{C}{n^{\alpha+1}}$$
for $$C=2^{\alpha+1}\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} \frac{2}{i^{\alpha+1}}$$

Comment: I may be added that $C = 2^{\alpha  + 2} \zeta (\alpha  + 1)$. Also, by Tannery's theorem, $$
n^{\alpha  + 1} \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n - 1} {\frac{1}{{i^{\alpha  + 1} }}\frac{1}{{(n - i)^{\alpha  + 1} }}}  \sim 2n^{\alpha  + 1} \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n/2} {\frac{1}{{i^{\alpha  + 1} }}\frac{1}{{(n - i)^{\alpha  + 1} }}}  \sim 2\zeta (\alpha  + 1)
$$ for large $n$.

Comment: @Gary Thank you for your interesting remark.